# bcp queryout creating empty file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp

I have a stored procedure that uses `bcp queryout` and populates the file with the results of

```
SELECT * FROM ##TempTable
```

Occasionally, the file created is empty. I know it cannot be permission based on the output location as the file is created and saved, so the `SELECT` must be returning zero rows. This is a production environment and I am not permitted to put any debugging etc to see what the count of the `SELECT` statement returns prior to the bcp line - but I know the table is populated as it is referenced later on in the sp and that section of the code never fails

Has anyone seen bcp act this way?

The switches I am using against bcp are

```
-t -T -c -S
```

Thanks

Comment: Face it: There is nothing wrong with BCP, your temp table has no rows in it. You need to follow that line of reasoning in order to troubleshoot. Do you have a DEV environment where you can reproduce? Are you able to run SQL Profiler?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check to ensure that none of your fields contain a NULL. Use ISNULL() to replace NULL with ''.